# Multiple Or in an IIF function

Tags: reporting-services

Given this data: [Complete Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeuAl.png)

I only want to get the Total_AR of those TransactionYrMonth=ParameterPeriod so I produced it using this code:

```
=IIF(
    IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Total_AR.Value)),0,
    Sum(IIF(Cdate(Fields!TransactionYrMnth.Value)=Cdate(Parameters!Period.Value),
    Fields!Total_AR.Value,0)
           )    
    )
```

From there, I got this dataset:
[Filtered Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX4Jn.png)

Now, what I need to do is to get the sum of the first 3 service months starting from January to March that is equal to the latest transaction month which is April.

So the sum should be equal to $204,329 + -$96,640 + -$259,008 = **-$151,319**

To make it possible, I tried to use a code like this:

```
=Sum(IIF(
      Cdate(Fields!TransactionYrMnth.Value)=Cdate(Parameters!Period.Value) And (
      Cdate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value)=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -3, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) Or
      Cdate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value)=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -2, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) Or
      Cdate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value)=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value))), Fields!Total_AR.Value,0
        ))
```

I have no luck producing it. I even got an error saying

> ‘Textbox11.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.

Anyone, please help?

Comment: Your Sum with IIf seems syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution already using this code:

```
=Sum(IIF(
        Cdate(Fields!TransactionYrMnth.Value)=Cdate(Parameters!Period.Value) And 
        CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) >= DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -3, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) And 
        CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) <= DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)), Fields!Total_AR.Value, 0
        )
    )
```